# using awk remove unwanted records whith particular fields

Tags: awk, multiline

How to view records, which does not have particular fields...
to begin with, my input need particular Record and field separator

```
BEGIN {
  RS="";
  FS="\n";
}
```

and here is my input:

```
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Networks menu (disabled)</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Networks</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="4"><Data ss:Type="String">Select</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Back</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="8"><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">&quot;Networks Sel&quot;,&quot;GPRC Mode&quot;</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
   </Row>



   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s93"><Data ss:Type="String">New Code?</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Cancel</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">-1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">&quot;?|New Code?&quot;</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s95"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s95"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s95"/>
   </Row>



   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s156"><Data ss:Type="String">New Message Arrived</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="String">ANIMATION_REC_MAIL</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Read</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Back</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Boolean">0</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s117"><Data ss:Type="String">-1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NOT EXIST </Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
   </Row>
```

How to view all input, exept ONE record, which second field is "New Code?" (here will be some regular expression)

Comment: Trying to parse/process XML with `awk` and other line-oriented tools is well known to cause insanity. (Can we get that put in the DSM?). You would do well to switch to tools specifically designed to deal with XML.

Comment: Awk is not line-oriented, it's record-oriented, so it's usually pretty easy to parse XML files with awk. There is also xmlawk if your file is too complicated for the vanilla version.

Comment: As I stood in front of my problem, I tried to copy with it using sed, but I hit the wall because sed is **line oriented**, than I discovered Record Separators in awk, and that was my eureka. Summing up, I had no idea that whole problem can be solved with "one-lineer: )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the blank line between records, you also need to set the `ORS` variable. You want to use awk's matching operator `~` on the second field.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {RS=""; FS="\n"; ORS="\n\n"} 
    $2 ~ /New Code\?/ {next} 
    {print}
'
```

As @EdMorton mentions, this can be written more concisely:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=""; FS="\n"; ORS="\n\n"} $2 !~ /New Code\?/'
```

Comment: You could replace `$2 ~ /New Code\?/ {next} {print}` with just `$2 !~ /New Code\?/`.

Comment: Guys, this is it! Many thanks! What a tricky one-liner :) but sth is wrong with my awk, first field $1 is empty, $2 is <Row> and the $3 is what I wanted, I dont get it...